HLS Converted Files Playing Without Audio
I have created an AWS Lambda function that triggers whenever a zip file containing audio files is uploaded to an S3 bucket. The Lambda function performs the following tasks:

Unzips the uploaded file.
Converts all the audio files inside the zip into HLS format (m3u8 and .aac files).
Uploads the converted files into a different S3 bucket.
Sends the S3 URLs of the converted audio files to a Supabase database via an HTTP request to a Supabase edge function.

The issue is that the conversion process completes successfully, and the output S3 bucket contains the expected files (two .m3u8 files and corresponding .aac files). However, when I try to play the .m3u8 files, there is no sound
Here's my lambda_fucntion.py:
import time
import json
import boto3
import zipfile
import requests
import os
import random
import shutil
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from media_converter_settings import get_job_settings  
from datetime import datetime


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
mediaconvert_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert')

# Env variables
MEDIACONVERT_ROLE = os.environ['MediaConvertRole']
TARGET_BUCKET = os.environ['targetBucket']
APPLICATION_NAME = os.environ['Application']
SUPABASE_EDGE_FUNCTION_URL = os.environ['SUPABASE_EDGE_FUNCTION_URL']
SUPABASE_AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['SUPABASE_AUTH']
WEBHOOK_AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['WEBHOOK_AUTH']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Starting Lambda Function Execution")
    try:
        print("Processing S3 Event")
        print(json.dumps(event, indent=2)) 

        bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        zip_file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
        tmp_dir = '/tmp/'


        try:
            s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=zip_file_key)
        except ClientError as e:
            print(f"Object not found or inaccessible: {e}")
            raise

        local_zip_path = os.path.join(tmp_dir, os.path.basename(zip_file_key))
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, zip_file_key, local_zip_path)

        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(tmp_dir)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error extracting files: {str(e)}")
            raise

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tmp_dir):
            output_paths = []
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

                if not file.lower().endswith(('.mp3', '.wav', '.aac', '.mp4', '.mov', '.mkv')):
                    continue

                base_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                unique_base_name = f"{base_name}_{int(time.time())}_{random.randint(1000, 9999)}"  

                media_key = f"temp_media/{file}"
                s3_client.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, media_key)

                input_s3_url = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{media_key}"
                job_settings = get_job_settings(TARGET_BUCKET, unique_base_name)
                full_output_path = create_mediaconvert_job(input_s3_url, job_settings,base_name)  
                output_paths.append({'name': base_name, 'url': full_output_path}) 


        try:
            shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
            print(f"Cleaned up /tmp directory.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error cleaning up /tmp directory: {e}")

        completion_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"

        response_data = {
            'status': 'success',
            'targetBucket': TARGET_BUCKET,
            'outputPaths': output_paths,
            'CompletionTime': completion_time
        }

        send_to_supabase(response_data)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Media files successfully processed and converted.')
        }


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        }

def create_mediaconvert_job(input_s3_url, job_settings,base_name, max_retries=5):
    """
    Creates a MediaConvert job with retry logic for throttling errors.
    """
    retries = 0
    while retries <= max_retries:
        try:
            job_settings['Inputs'][0]['FileInput'] = input_s3_url
            response = mediaconvert_client.create_job(
                Role=MEDIACONVERT_ROLE,
                Settings=job_settings
            )
            job_id = response['Job']['Id']
            output_path = check_mediaconvert_job_status(job_id, base_name) 
            output_groups = response['Job']['Settings']['OutputGroups']
            print("Output Groups Configuration:", json.dumps(output_groups, indent=2))
            return output_path
            # return job_id
        except ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'TooManyRequestsException':
                retries += 1
                delay = min(2 ** retries + random.uniform(0, 1), 60) 
                print(f"TooManyRequestsException: Retrying in {delay:.2f} seconds...")
                time.sleep(delay)
            else:
                print(f"Error creating MediaConvert job: {e}")
                raise
    raise Exception("Failed to create MediaConvert job after multiple retries.")

def check_mediaconvert_job_status(job_id,base_name, poll_interval=10,timeout=600):
    """
    Check the status of a MediaConvert job with polling and timeout logic.
    """
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise Exception("Timeout exceeded while waiting for the job to complete.")

        try:
            response = mediaconvert_client.get_job(Id=job_id)
            status = response['Job']['Status']
            print(f"Job Status: {status}")

            if status == 'COMPLETE':
                print("Job completed successfully.")
                outputs = response['Job']['Settings']['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['HlsGroupSettings']['Destination']
                replace_prefix = "https://********.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"
                modified_base_name = f"{base_name}_audio.m3u8"
                clean_output_path = outputs.replace("s3://*********/",replace_prefix)
                full_output_path = f"{clean_output_path}{modified_base_name}"  
                return full_output_path
            elif status == 'ERROR':
                error_message = response['Job'].get('ErrorMessage', 'Unknown error')
                raise Exception(f"Job failed with error: {error_message}")
            else:
                print("Job still in progress, checking again...")
            time.sleep(poll_interval)

        except ClientError as e:
            print(f"Error checking job status: {e}")
            raise e
        
def send_to_supabase(data):
    """
    Sends a POST request to the Supabase Edge Function, sending data.
    """

    try:
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {SUPABASE_AUTH_TOKEN}",
            "WEBHOOK_AUTH": f"Bearer {WEBHOOK_AUTH_TOKEN}"
        }
        response = requests.post(SUPABASE_EDGE_FUNCTION_URL, json=data, headers=headers)


        return {
            "statusCode": response.status_code,
            "body": response.text
        }

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error sending data to Supabase: {e}")
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": f"Error sending data to Supabase: {str(e)}"
        }

media_converter_settings.py:
import time
import random

def get_job_settings(output_bucket, base_name):
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    unique_base_name = f"{base_name}_{timestamp}_{random.randint(1000, 9999)}"
    
    job_settings = {
        'Inputs': [
            {
                'AudioSelectors': {
                    'Audio Selector 1': {
                        'DefaultSelection': 'DEFAULT',
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        'OutputGroups': [
            {
                'CustomName': 'HLS',
                'Name': 'Apple HLS',
                'Outputs': [
                    {
                        'ContainerSettings': {
                            'Container': 'M3U8',
                            'M3u8Settings': {
                                'AudioFramesPerPes': 4,
                                'PcrControl': 'PCR_EVERY_PES_PACKET',
                                'PmtPid': 480,
                                'PrivateMetadataPid': 503,
                                'ProgramNumber': 1,
                                'PatInterval': 0,
                                'PmtInterval': 0,
                                'Scte35Source': 'NONE',
                                'TimedMetadata': 'NONE',
                                'AudioPids': [482, 483]
                            }
                        },
                        'AudioDescriptions': [
                            {   
                                'AudioSourceName': 'Audio Selector 1',
                                'CodecSettings': {
                                    'Codec': 'AAC',
                                    'AacSettings': {
                                        "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix": "NORMAL",
                                        'Bitrate': 128000,
                                        'RateControlMode': 'CBR',
                                        'CodingMode': 'CODING_MODE_2_0',
                                        "CodecProfile": "LC",
                                        "RawFormat": "NONE",
                                        'SampleRate': 48000,
                                        'Specification': 'MPEG4'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        'OutputSettings': {
                            'HlsSettings': {
                                'SegmentModifier': '$dt$',
                                'IFrameOnlyManifest': 'EXCLUDE'
                            }
                        },
                        'NameModifier': '_audio'
                    }
                ],
                'OutputGroupSettings': {
                    'Type': 'HLS_GROUP_SETTINGS',
                    'HlsGroupSettings': {
                        'ManifestDurationFormat': 'INTEGER',
                        'MinSegmentLength': 5,
                        'SegmentLength': 10,
                        'Destination': f's3://{output_bucket}/assets/AUDIOBOOKS/HLS/{unique_base_name}/',
                        'OutputSelection': 'MANIFESTS_AND_SEGMENTS',
                        "DirectoryStructure": "SINGLE_DIRECTORY",
                        'ClientCache': 'ENABLED',
                        'StreamInfResolution': 'INCLUDE',
                        'CodecSpecification': 'RFC_4281'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    return job_settings

I have tried multiple configurations in the media_converter_settings.py file, including changing the bit rate, modifying the audio source settings, and adjusting codec configurations. Despite these changes, the issue persists.
I also tested the generated .m3u8 files using the HLS demo player (HLS.js), and I didn’t encounter any errors during playback. Additionally, I checked the CloudWatch logs of my Lambda function, and there are no errors related to this issue.
At this point, I’m stuck. I’ve searched extensively online and tried various AI tools, but nothing has helped so far.
I would really appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this problem.
